# Is apache airflow required pickle5 to start scheduler or celery?

Tags: airflow, pickle, airflow-scheduler

We have python3.6.8 version in Linux server.

We started installing apache-airflow==2.1.3 and after installing while we are starting the scheduler by below command

```
airflow scheduler
```

throws an below error:

```
**ValueError: unsupported pickle protocol: 5**
```

is there something i am missing , pls suggest